# SQL Select only unique values in column

Tags: sql

I have the below query that is pulling from a table where a record (Employee ID) can have more than 1 row of data. Because of this I have some rows with the highest (Max) EXAM_DATE. I have added in the MAX function into the SELECT Statement, however I am still retrieving rows with 2 or more dates per empl. This must be something simply that I am overlooking. Any help is appreciated.

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT A.EMPLID, A.BUSINESS_TITLE, A.DEPTID, A.LOCATION, A.LAST_NAME, 
A.FIRST_NAME, A.MIDDLE_NAME, 
MAX(CONVERT(CHAR(10),D.EXAM_DT,121))AS EXAM_DATE, D.EXAM_TYPE_CD, 
(CONVERT(CHAR(10),D.GH_EXPIRE_DATE,121)) AS EXPIRE_DATE, AA.NAME AS 
Manager_Name

FROM ((PS_EMPLOYEES A INNER JOIN PS_EMPLMT_SRCH_QRY A1 ON (A.EMPLID = 
A1.EMPLID AND A.EMPL_RCD = A1.EMPL_RCD AND  A1.OPRID = 'HD065' )) 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_GHS_HS_PPDSCRN D ON A.EMPLID = D.EMPLID)
 --LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_GHS_REPORTS_TO H ON A.EMPLID = H.EMPLID
   LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_EMPLOYEES AA ON AA.POSITION_NBR = A.REPORTS_TO 
     AND (( AA.EFFDT = 
     (SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_EMPLOYEES A_ED 
      WHERE AA.POSITION_NBR = A_ED.POSITION_NBR 
      AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10)) ))
   WHERE ( ( A.EFFDT = 
    (SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_EMPLOYEES A_ED 
    WHERE A.EMPLID = A_ED.EMPLID 
      AND A.EMPL_RCD = A_ED.EMPL_RCD 
      AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10)) 
   AND A.EFFSEQ = 
    (SELECT MAX(A_ES.EFFSEQ) FROM PS_EMPLOYEES A_ES 
    WHERE A.EMPLID = A_ES.EMPLID 
      AND A.EMPL_RCD = A_ES.EMPL_RCD 
      AND A.EFFDT = A_ES.EFFDT) 

      AND D.EXAM_TYPE_CD = 'PPD'))
      AND A.EMPL_STATUS = 'A' 

--AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT D.EMPLID, COUNT(*) AS 'TotalOccur' FROM PS_GHS_HS_PPDSCRN D GROUP BY D.EMPLID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

 GROUP BY A.EMPLID, A.BUSINESS_TITLE, A.DEPTID, A.LOCATION, A.LAST_NAME, 
 A.FIRST_NAME, A.MIDDLE_NAME, D.EXAM_TYPE_CD, D.GH_EXPIRE_DATE, AA.NAME
 ORDER BY 5
```

I tried running it with the Commented out code for NOT EXISTS, however when I run this I do not retrieve any results.

**Sample Output:**

[image]

Comment: Before spending time and effort asking questions, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. It will help you get better answers, faster!

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Using MS SQL Server. I did add into the WHERE Clause this: ( AND D.EXAM_DT = (SELECT MAX(DD.EXAM_DT) FROM PS_GHS_HS_PPDSCRN DD WHERE D.EMPLID = DD.EMPLID) )      This seems to work, is there any better way of accomplishing this though?

Comment: That's a fine way of handling it

Comment: I'm just curious why having the MAX in the SELECT clause originally wouldn't have worked in this case...?

Comment: Because if you look at the two rows you highlighted in your sample output, there are two columns that have unique values, `EXAM_DATE` and `EXPIRE_DATE`.  Using `MAX(EXAM_DATE)` only will not combine these rows, because `EXPIRE_DATE` is still unique and won't group into a single row.

Comment: So I would need to get MAX for both EXAM_DATE and EXPIRE_DATE in the SELECT clause? Just trying to think of other possibilities for creating the same logic in the SELECT clause.

Answer (score 0):

The MAX in your WHERE should be fine.

Your EXPIRE_DATE is also different between the two records, and as the EXPIRE_DATE is included in the GROUP BY, it will cause the "duplicate".